# Design Opinions Needed: Template Databases/Tables for users

Tags: mysql, database-design, multiple-databases

I need professional programmers/DBAs to bounce my idea off of and to know if it would/could even work.  Please read below and give me any information that may break this theory.  Thanks.

---

**Overview of Website Idea:**
The website will be used by sports card collectors to chat, answer questions on forums, showcase their cards/box breaks, trade/sell to/with other users, and keep a collection of their cards.

**Design Issue:**
A user can have an unlimited number of cards.  This could make for some very large tables.

**Design Question:**
I do not want to limit the users on how many cards they can have in their collection on the site.  If they have 5 copies of one card, and would rather have 5 records, one for each card, then that is their prerogative.  This may also be necessary as each of the cards may be in a different condition.  However, by allowing this to happen, this means that having only one table to store all records for all users is not even close to an option.  I know sports card collectors with over 1,000,000 cards.

I was thinking that by either creating a table or a database for each user, it would allow for faster queries.  All databases would be on the same server (I don't know who my host will be yet, only in design phase currently).  There would be a main database with data that everyone would need (the base item while the user table/database would have a reference to the base item).  I do see that it is possible for a field to be a foreign key from another database, so I know my idea in that aspect is possible, but overall I'm not sure what the best idea is.

I see most hosts say "unlimited number of databases" which is what got me to thinking about a database for each user.  I could use this for that users posts on threads, their collection items, their preferences, and other information.  Also, by having each user have a different table/database, if someone's table needed to be reindexed for whatever reason, it wouldn't affect the other users.

However, my biggest concern in either fashion would be additions/deletions to the structure of the tables/databases.  I'm pretty sure a script could be written to make the necessary changes, but it seems like a pretty high risk.  For instance, I'm pretty sure that I could write a script to add a field to a specific table in each database, or all of the like tables, but then to verify them it could prove difficult.

---

Any ideas you can throw out there for me would be greatly appreciated.  I've been trying to work on this site for over a year now and keep getting stuck on the database design because of my worry of too large of tables, slow response time, and if the number of users grow, breaking some constraints set by phpmyadmin/MySQL.  I also don't want to get half way through the database building and then think that there's a better way to do it.  I know there may be multiple ways to do it, but what is the most common practice for it?  Thank you all very much.

Comment: "This could make for some very large tables".  Define very large more carefully than "collectors with over 1,000,000 cards"?  How many collectors have this?  How will they enter all this data?

Comment: I'm still working on that as an "upload from file" would be difficult.  I'm trying to refrain from users creating their own card descriptions as it makes it difficult for some users to find what they want when looking to trade.  But not many have more than 1,000,000 cards, on average I'd say each user averages about 25,000 cards.  But the site I currently use has over 100,000 users, so you're looking at 2,500,000,000 records.  I'm not sure if that's a feasible number of records for one table.  And if it grows, who knows.

Comment: And the reason why I'm trying to keep users from creating their own card descriptions is because there are already pretty decently defined structures for card descriptions out there.  On most collecting sites that have a database for you to search, you have to look for your card, add it to your collection, then update the quantities.  I may have to work with some of the current sites to have a web service between us to transfer information, but I don't think I want users to upload a file unless they followed very strict instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was thinking that by either creating a table or a database for each user, it would allow for faster queries.

That's false.  A single data base will be faster.

1,000,000 cards per user isn't really a very large number unless you have 1,000,000 users.

Multiple databases is an administration nightmare.  A single database is always preferred.

---

> my worry of too large of tables, slow response time, and if the number of users grow, breaking some constraints set by phpmyadmin/MySQL

You'll be hard-pressed to exceed MySQL limits.

Slow response is part of your application and details of your SQL queries more than anything else.

Finally.   And Most Important.

All technology goes out of date.  Eventually, you **must** replace something.  In order to get to the point where you're forced to upgrade, you must first get something running.

Don't worry about "large database" until you have numbers of rows in the billions.

Don't worry about "long-term" solutions because all software technology expires.  Quickly.

---

Regarding number of users.

Much of web interaction is time spent interacting with the browser through JavaScript.  Or reading a page.  Clicks are actually sort of rare.  MySQL on a reasonably large server should handle 30 or more nearly concurrent queries with sub-second response.  Your application will probably take very little time to format and start sending an HTML page.  Things can rip along at a very, very good clip on a typical server.

If your database design avoids the dreaded full-table scan.

You must have proper indexes for the most common queries.

Now.  What are the odds of 30 nearly concurrent requests?  If a user only clicks once every 10 seconds (they have to read the page, fill in the form, re-read the page, think, drink their beer) then the odds of 30 clicks in a single second means you have to have 300 *concurrent* users.  Considering that people have other things to do in their lives, that means you must have 50,000 or so users (figuring they're spending 1 hour each week on your site.)

Comment: So more than it is the number of users accessing the table and how many rows that are in that table, it's more about how the table itself is designed?

Comment: It's all about normalization, denormalization and indexing.  A query with an index that fetches a small number of rows uses the index tree and runs in (almost) constant time irrespective of the size of the database.  A query without an index that scans the table is slow no matter how small the table is.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I do worry too much about getting something up and then immediately needing to upgrade it which is why whenever I design something, I look to see what the next possible solution is before I even have the problem out there.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't go down the path of creating a database for every user... that will create countless headaches for you: data integrity issues, referential integrity issues, administrative issues...

As long as your table is well normalized and indexed, I don't think a table with hundreds of millions of rows is prohibitively large.

Instead, I would just start with a simple table design.  If your site is wildly successful, it wouldn't be any extra effort to implement [partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-overview.html) or [sharding](http://www.scalebase.com/how-to-implement-mysql-sharding/) in MySql down the road as opposed to scaling out right off the bat.

Answer (score 1):

If I where in your shoes I would start with one database and one table and not worry too much about the possible size of the table. If you ever get so successful and reach the size you imagine you would probably have a lot more resources and knowledge of your domain to make a better informed decision. Once that happens, you can also consider noSql solution such as [HBase](http://hbase.apache.org/), [Mondgodb](http://www.mongodb.org/) and others that allow for horizontal scaling(unlimited size) with some limitations that businesses that deal with big data are bound to face. You can also use [mysql partitions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-overview.html) or other sharding solutions. So, go build your product with one table and don't sweat this problem until you absolutely need to. Good luck!